# add all column names with a prefix in Hive

Tags: hive, concatenation, alter-table, alter

I have a table with thousands of columns, need to merge with the other table with thousands of columns. I need to add pre-fix to avoid conflict, any quick way to change all columns in one table with a pre-fix?

Comment: Interesting, we cannot alias all columns at once in the SELECT part

Answer (score 1):

If you have necessary permissions to update meta-store you can try this query which will update all the column names of your table with a prefix

```
UPDATE COLUMNS_V2 C JOIN  TBLS T
ON C.CD_ID= T.TBL_ID AND 
T.TBL_NAME='table_name' SET C.COLUMN_NAME =CONCAT('prefix_',C.COLUMN_NAME) ;
```

in the above query , replace the following :

**'table_name'**: table name with columns for which you wanted to add prefix for.

**'prefix_'  :** prefix of your choice , example 'tbl_'

Comment: Thanks. what are CD_ID and TBL_ID here, table properties?

Comment: yes @Jin , TBL_ID and CD_ID are the Primary key and reference key columns in hive metastore tables TBLS and COLUMNS_V2